# Finding two consecutive 1's in a bitstring in less then n time?

Tags: algorithm, bit, bitstring

I am trying to figure out a way to see if a bitstring has 2 consecutive ones in the bitstring size n in less then n time.

For example, lets say we had a bitstring size 5 (index 0-4).  If index 1 and 3 were both 0's, I could return false.  But if they were both ones then I may have to do 5 peeks to find my answer.

The bitstring doesn't have to be length 5.  For simplicity's sake, lets say it can be between 3 and 8.

Comment: You will need n-1 peeks (for n=4 check if 0 & 1 or 1 & 2 or 2 & 3)..

Comment: @Lex: you may be able to do it in fewer "peeks", e.g. if bits 0 and 1 are both 0 then there is no need to check bits 1 and 2, you can skip to bits 2 and 3. So in the best case there might only be around n / 2 peeks needed (assuming no 11s found).

Comment: You can AND your bit string with a mask ie bitstring 0110. Do an AND with 1100, 0110 an 0011. If that returns the mask, than you will have found it.

Comment: Asymptotically this will be O(n) no matter how you slice it, so your situation is probably more of a micro-optimization problem. This is the sort of thing where a non-portable solution that takes full advantage of the architecture is likely worth the effort.

Answer (score 15):

Simplest solution might be to bitwise `AND` the original string with a version of itself which has been shifted left or right by 1 bit. If the resulting bit string in non-zero then you have at least one `11` in there:

```
test = (src & (src << 1));
```